# A slightly various form of Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions

Tags: prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Are there infinitely many primes of the form $2n(n+1)+1$?

Comment: Thank, sorry I had a typo on the coefficient.

Comment: There is an old conjecture of Hardy, that if $a$ is positive, and $a,b,c$ are pairwise relatively prime, and $a+b$ and $c$ are not both even, and $an^2+bn+c$ is not a perfect square, then $an^2+bn+c$ is prime for infinitely many $n$. This has not been proved for **any** $(a,b,c)$, Neither has it been refuted for any $(a,b,c)$.

Comment: Edit: I should not have called it a conjecture of Hardy, it is undoubtedly much older. Hardy has a *quantitative* version, giving conjectured estimates, for "good" $a,b,c$, for the number of primes of that form $\le x$.

Comment: I have little knowledge on analytic number theory. Any comments are welcome. I fixed my condition again.

Comment: The new quadratic is still of the type that is conjectured to represent infinitely many primes. For various simple quadratics, the conjecture of Hardy and Littlewood fits computational data quite well. However, even for the simplest quadratic $n^2+1$, it is not known whether there are infinitely many primes of that form.

Comment: Your question is equivalent to whether or not there are an infinite amount of even semi-primes of the form n²+1.

Answer (score 1):

This is a completely open question; see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulam_spiral#Hardy_and_Littlewood.27s_Conjecture_F if you are interested in some background, and a link to the more general Bunyakovsky's conjecture.